# Python multiprocessing imap iterates over whole itarable

Tags: python, iterator, python-multiprocessing

In my code I am trying to achieve the following:

1. I get each result as soon as any of the processes finish
2. Next iteration must only be called whenever it is necessary (if it is converted into a list, I will have RAM issues)

To my knowledge `imap` `from multiprocessing` module should be perfect for this task, but this code:

```py
import os
import time

def txt_iterator():
    for i in range(8): 
        yield i
        print('iterated', i)

def func(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in pool.imap( func, txt_iterator() ):
        print('P2', i)
    pool.close()
```

Has this output:

```
iterated 0
iterated 1
...
iterated 7
# 5 second pause
P2 0
P2 1
P2 2
P2 3
# 5 second pause
P2 4
P2 5
P2 6
P2 7
```

Meaning that it iterates through the whole iterable and only then starts assigning tasks to processes. As far as I could find in the docs, this behavior is only expected from `.map` (the iteration part).

The expected output is (may vary because they run concurrently, but you get the idea):

```
iterated 0
...
iterated 3
# 5 second pause
P2 0
...
P2 3
iterated 4
...
iterated 7
# 5 second pause
P2 4
...
P2 7
```

I am sure that I am missing something here but in case I completely misunderstand how this function works, I would appreciate any alternative that will work as intended.

Comment: If you change the 8 to 8000, you'll notice that the child processes do begin work before all 8000 items have been yielded. (Also, if you slow down the yielding at all, e.g. with `time.sleep(0.1)` after the yield, you'll see this more clearly.)

Comment: try adding a time.sleep(1) to your generator, and you will see that it's not consuming your iterator before sending of tasks. But, that being said, I'm not exactly sure why you get this behaviour in the first place.

Comment: FWIW, though, looking at the implementation for `.imap()`, it doesn't (as we could plainly see) guarantee that the input iterator is consumed at the same pace the workers finish their tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imap` doesn't guarantee consuming the input iterator at the same pace the workers finish their tasks.

You can use a `threading.BoundedSemaphore` (even if you're only using a single thread) to have the input generator wait until the for loop has consumed an item:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time


def txt_iterator(sem: threading.BoundedSemaphore):
    for i in range(30):
        sem.acquire()
        yield i
        print("iterated", i)


def func(x):
    print("starting work on", x)
    time.sleep(1)
    return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sem = threading.BoundedSemaphore(4)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    for i in pool.imap(func, txt_iterator(sem)):
        sem.release()
        print("P2", i)
    pool.close()
```

Comment: That's crazy to me how this is listed everywhere as a "feature" of `imap`, yet it is not guaranteed. But your answer works, so thank you.

Comment: The fact that the code does not raise a `ValueError` exception due to too many releases being performed strongly suggests that using a plain `Semapore` suffices in this case. But I might suggest using a semaphore initialization value that is at least twice the pool size *if  you are not otherwise constrained*. In this way whenever a task completes the idle process does not always have to wait for a new task to be enqueued; there is a better chance that there will be one on the task queue ready to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

`imap` in general does *not* iterate through the *entire* passed *iterable* before it starts running tasks. But it can (and often does) enqueue far more tasks initially than the pool size you specified. Because `imap` can enqueue tasks faster than the pool processes can be started and dispatched to take items off the task queue, in some cases when the *iterable* size is not very large, then you could have the case where no tasks start running until all elements of the passed *iterable* have been enqueued. But, again, that is not the general rule.

If you are constrained by resources (for example, the items being enqueued on the pool's task queue are very large), then the answer posted by AKX is how you could limit the rate in which tasks are enqueued. But do see my comment to that answer. If `imap` only enqueued initially a number of tasks equal to the pool size and subsequently only when a task completed and a pool process became idle, then the pool process would be idle doing no useful work until a new task can be enqueued. This could result in an unnecessary delay. So in general it is better to have tasks already on the task queue ready to run as soon as a task completes. This I suppose is the rationale for what you see.